# Titanium compatibility with Android

Tags: android, titanium

Will Titanium work properly on all android sdk versions (1.5, 1.6, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2).....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the research I've done, yes, I believe so.  I'd recommend trying it out.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is.

But be warned that while Titanium has its strengths, it also has its weaknesses (ie; memory).

If you're working on a project for a client or are just starting your journey into mobile development, I would recommend learning how to code a native application. At least that gives you some options if you run into troubles. I've been burned a couple of times.

Answer (score 1):

Titanium works with all android SDKs .You just have to make some changes to make it work with all SDKs. Titanium works with sdk 2.1 and below without any changes. But in order to make it work with 2.2 and above you have to add a symbolic link of adb file which is in 
platform-tools(source) folder to tools(target).

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally the platform-level support for a particular feature is different between the iOS and Android.  For instance, the underlying audio support is significantly better on iOS; many features are simply missing on Android (we eventually patched them ourselves).

In addition, the way that the underlying platform's primitives are wrapped differs, so that code that is correct Javascript will result in incorrect Java on Android.  An example we came across was related to the treatment of `null` and `undefined` when used with the `Ti.App.Properties.setXXX` functions.  This issues are becoming fewer and farther between, as mentioned, but there are still issues not just related to UI.

I suggest you make a point of continuously developing and testing on **both** platforms; you'll find incompatibilities (mostly related to leaky abstractions) and their workarounds more easily that way.

Answer (score 0):

Well it works great for the cross platform Execution.
The Only problem is that when user want to compare the iphone version & Android Version by developing same code.
iphone is excellent as per its gesture supports & fine UI works.While Android is still improving the terms.
So you should firstly check your terms and requirement then Go a head with Titanium. OtherWise 
Appcelerator consistently working around all the native support as well as common features.
you need to find the possibilities in proposal for the Framework.it will be great approach & future perception as well.